# Comparing integers in drools causes cast exception

Tags: java, integer, drools, classcastexception

I have a simple Drools rule where I am converting a string to an integer and then comparing it with another integer. Like so:

```
when
    $list : List(size > 0 )
    $m1 : Map() from $list.get(0)
    $var1 : Map(stringToInt(this["number"]) <= 0) from $list.get(0)
```

This should check if the string value of "number" in my map is less than or equal to 0 after being converted. stringToInt is just a helper function I wrote that calls Integer.parseInt and catches exceptions.

I get this error though when I try to run the rule:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Boolean
    at org.mvel2.ast.Negation.getReducedValueAccelerated(Negation.java:48)
```

The dialect is set to java and my version of drools is 6.4.0. How do I get around this error?

EDIT: string to int:

```
public static int stringToInt(String s) {
    try {
        int num = Integer.parseInt(s);
        return num;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not knowing all the details I can only say that this works with 6.4.0. Edit your Q, providing stringToInt and the Drools version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me.

Creating a session, all options at default. Inserting:

```
Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put( "number", "4711" );
List<Map<String,String>> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add( map );
kieSession.insert( list );
```

Running a drl:

```
import static map.Main.stringToInt;
import java.util.*;
rule "int from map"
when
  $list : List(size > 0 ) 
  $m1 : Map() from $list.get(0)
  $var1 : Map(stringToInt(this["number"]) > 0 ) from $list.get(0)
then
  System.out.println( "got 4711" );
end
```

I even kept the redundant first (empty) `Map` pattern.

Check that your classpath includes `mvel2-2.2.8.Final.jar` and no other version. (This is where class `Negation` is.)

Check that you have reported the rule *as it is in your code*, not omitting the real trigger of the exception.

Comment: I had three k,v pairs in my map for the knowledge session and for some reason when I take out one of them, this rule works. If I add it back in, the rule fails. The way I am firing the rule is through a JUnit test with a RuleNameEqualsAgendaFilter. The file containing the rule is also filled with other rules.

Comment: The issue was that a different rule was being checked when I added the extra field to my knowledge session. It seems that even with the rule name filter, drools still validates all the rules in the file before firing the filtered one. One of the rules was having it's condition matched when I added the extra field in my map and there was a syntax error on it.